# Mongoose getter to convert image buffer to string? (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, multer

I've created a simple node backend app based on ebay. I'm trying to make a react frontend app to go with it.

The user can sell an item and can submit a photo to go with it. The item is added to a mongodb collection and the photo is added using multer. Below the field 'file' is the photo.

Is it possible to use a getter with mongoose to convert the image buffer to a string, for use by the frontend?

Many thanks.

The Item schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        min:1,
        max:256
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        min:1,
        max:1024
    },
    condition:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        enum:['New','Used']
    },
    user:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        require:true
    },
    expiresAt:{
        type:Date,
        require:true
    },
    maxBid:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Bid',
        require:true,
        default: undefined
    },
    file: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
      }
},
{ virtuals: true ,versionKey: false, id: false, timestamps: { createdAt: true, updatedAt: false } })

itemSchema.virtual('status').get(function () { 
    return this.expiresAt > new Date() ? 'Open to offers' : 'Completed'
});

itemSchema.virtual('timeLeft').get(function () { 
    const total     = Date.parse(this.expiresAt) - Date.parse(new Date())
    if (total < 0) return '00:00:00:00'
    const seconds   = String(Math.floor( (total/1000) % 60 )).padStart(2, '0')
    const minutes   = String(Math.floor( (total/1000/60) % 60 )).padStart(2, '0')
    const hours     = String(Math.floor( (total/(1000*60*60)) % 24 )).padStart(2, '0')
    const days      = Math.floor( total/(1000*60*60*24) )
    return `${days}:${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
});

itemSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true })
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema, 'items');
module.exports = { Item };
```

The get method to show available items:

```
router.get('/available', async(req,res)=>{
    const items = await Item.find(
        {expiresAt:{ $gt: new Date()}},{__v:0, description:0, createdAt:0})
        .sort({expiry_date: -1})         
        .populate({
            path:"maxBid",
            model:"Bid",
            options: { select: {"price":1}}})             
        .populate({
            path:"user",
            model:"User",
            options: { select: {"username":1}}})
    res.send(items)    
})
```

An item stored on mongodb:

[image]

The JSON returned by the available items route (currently just one and with the buffer array replaced with the buffer array replaced with 'BUFFERDATA'):

```
[
  {
    "file": {
      "data": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": ['BUFFERDATA']
      },
      "contentType": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "_id": "633db529bf13d1cb7f9ba7f0",
    "title": "faberge egg",
    "condition": "Used",
    "user": {
      "_id": "62588f89dbc142710869a615",
      "username": "Olga"
    },
    "expiresAt": "2022-10-30T21:30:00.000Z",
    "status": "Open to offers",
    "timeLeft": "24:09:16:44"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you store the path of the image in your database instead of its data.
Storing images directly in a database causes the database to get too massive and slow.

You can use [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to store and rename your image file on the disk and then use its path to store it in your database.